# Excel Shell() Args to/from Calc.exe

Tags: excel, function, shell, calculator, factorial

MS's new calculator can do non-integer (decimal) N! .  Excel's internal calculator still only returns nearest integer value for FACT().

In order to run non-integer hypergeometric and multinomial distributions in Excel (drawing from more than one cell), I wanted to use:
Shell ("Calc.exe"),1
to open an instance of the calculator, and then pass ByVal DOUBLE Args to get the values for the non-integer factorials.

Non-integer factorials are Gamma integrals, not gamma distributions, so I don't see any internal Excel function that will do it.

So, can it be done?

Is there a table of arguments that represents the function 'keys' within calculator that can be called within the shell so I can :

- Pass ByVal a non-integer (2.1) to the calculator
- Pass the instruction (factorial), 
  and
- return the answer to the desired field  (Sheet!B$3$) ?

Any help / leads greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it rounds at the 14th place, so THANK YOU, THANK YOU!  So you know, I took a finite field under an Exponential Distribution, so all of the values are decimals.  But each nth area section in that field has a different probability distribution. So to choose non-integer values with varying probabilities requires the Gamma.  Great idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that `FACT(n) = Gamma(n+1)` it's probably simpler to use Excel's `GAMMALN` (natural log of gamma):

```
EXP(GAMMALN(n+1))
```

This will work with non-integers.
Hope that helps